# How to Use nativescript-autocomplete plugin with nativescript angular?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am not able to make  [plugin](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-autocomplete) work with angular project template .GitHub shows only code in native and XML .Sample plugin code works but unfortunately no angular support or help given. I am not able show on angular template.
relevant code i am using

detail.component.ts

```
registerElement("AutoComplete", () => require("nativescript-autocomplete").AutoComplete);

public list :Array = ['1','2','3','4','567'] ; 

public itemTapped(args){

console.log("tapped");
```

}

detail.component.html

```
<AutoComplete items=""{{list}}"" itemTap="itemTapped($event)"> </AutoComplete>
```

i am getting exception on console while page loads and autocompletion doesnt work

```
this.items.forEach is not a function inside plugin code .that line is with definition of AutoComplete.prototype.itemsUpdate inside autocomplete.android.js plugin source
```

Debugging into plugin source it breaks at initialization time :

```
'AutoComplete.prototype.itemsUpdate = function (items) {
    var arr = Array.create(java.lang.String, this.items.length);
    this.items.forEach(function (item, index) {
        arr[index] = item;
    });
    var ad = new android.widget.ArrayAdapter(app.android.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
    this._android.setAdapter(ad);
};'
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at nativescript-telerik-ui plugin (https://www.nativescript.org/ui-for-nativescript). It has a free version and pro version which includes an AutoCompleteTextView like component. Unfortunately it is not supported for Angular yet but it will be in the next release of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In detail.component.html

```
<AutoComplete [items]="list" (itemTap)="itemTapped($event)"> </AutoComplete>
```

in details.component.ts add

```
public list:any= ['1','2','3','4','567'] ; 

itemTapped(ev){
//console.log(ev); your code
}
```

Issue in npm version. Clone the [repository](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-autocomplete).

Replace all the files in node_modules/nativescript-autocomplete ,expect screenshot, demo folders and git related files. And try the solution

Comment: i forgot to  mention  event code in question .I have updated question .This exception raises silently on console while page loads.Its not issue with event.Something wrong from initialization part of plugin itself.

Comment: did you applied my changes?

Comment: Just replace detail.component.html

Comment: event code was there before.I just replaced binding syntax as you mentioned .But now error message changed to  Cannot read property 'setAdapter' of undefined

Comment: @Sadiq. Updated the answer

Comment: Still same error Cannot read property 'setAdapter' of undefined .Can you share any working  sample nativescript angular project if possible

Comment: do tns install and Replace all the files in node_modules/nativescript-autocomplete  as i said. make sure it should contain *.d.ts and *.ts files

Comment: I dont get your question. If the answer solves your question. Please accept the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: sorry had power failure and could not complete my words yesterday .i have  deleted partialy committed sentance.The issue still persist if we use <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet> .initially on first load it will work ,navigating to other page and returning will raise same error. i am not well versed in anguar 2 .Is it issue due to caching and all ? .could you check with page-router-outlet ?

Comment: @Sadiq. Ask this as different question. Because it is related to angular2.
Hint: Try to work without autocomplete in routes and integrate with any child component.